# Dockerfile - use environment variable from env file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, environment-variables

I have a docker compose setup where I want to use environment variables from env file in my dockerfile. I want to use these variables during the build time since I use this version number in concatenating the string in order to form a download URL.

Here I wrote part of the files I'm using just to keep the focus on the point of my question.

.env

```
MY_APP_VER=v1.2.3
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  my-app:
    build: .
    container_name: my_app
    environment:
      - my_app_version=$MY_APP_VER
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM scratch
ENV my_app_ver=$my_app_version
RUN echo $my_app_ver
```

I have checked various sources but without any success. I'm not sure if this is even possible or am I using the wrong syntax (should I use quotes or no e.g. "$my_app_ver" or curly brackets ${my_app_ver}).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For version 3.8 you can do it in the following way

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  my-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - ${CONTAINER_PORT}:${PORT} # for example
    env_file: .env
    container_name: my-app-${NODE_ENV} # for example
    environment: 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME} # for example
      my_app_version: ${MY_APP_VER} # for your case
```

Find more information in [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option)

Also, you can find more information about the usage of env variables in Dockerfile and docker-compose [here](https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/)

Comment: Thanks! Can I use these params in the Dockerfile during the build? And how?

Comment: Please have a look @SašaVranić https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/. It can be helpful I think.

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option called `env-file` in docker-compose, that you can leverage: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option

```
version: "3"
services:
  my-app:
    build: .
    container_name: my_app
    env_file:
    - .env.dev
```

Be aware, that the `.env` file is loaded by default, if it is present in the current context. So you only have to use `env_file`, if it is named differently or is in a different folder.

Comment: I have .env file in my directory. If understand currently, if env file it is called differently then I have to use env_file param in the docker-compose.yml. my question is how to use end vars in the Dockerfile since currently I'm not able to use it. So I wanted to check what is wrong with my approach